# Discord bot keeps running into an error when run in vs code

Tags: python, discord

I keep running into an error when I run this. It ran smoothly in replit but it gives me this long weird error when I run it on vs code. It says something about a certificate and Im not sure whats the problem. ERROR: [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]

```
    import discord
    import os
    import requests
    import json
    import random
    
    client = discord.Client()
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
    
    client.run('Pasted my token here')
```

Heres the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1089, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1119, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 534, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trionnayio/Documents/Catto Bot.py", line 13, in <module>
    client.run('OTk0NDg3MDgyNzI4ODMzMDI0.GmFHDY.b8M5lgDEV26cTVKFFOb_5FbpGDp1oaq7Qge3cU')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
```

Comment: You might want to regenerate your bot token, it's in the traceback

Comment: Still doesnt work :(

Comment: I just tested the code and it seemed to work for me - what are you running it on(any proxies, firewalls etc)?

Comment: @Jaffa Wdym what I am running it on. Im currently running it on vs code macbook pro and my firewall is off.

Comment: Omg I fixed it myself :D. I just went to python 3.10 folder, clicked on Certificate Command and it automatically downloaded smth in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I just went to python 3.10 folder, clicked on Certificate Command and it automatically downloaded some stuff in the terminal. After that, it ran smoothly without any errors :)))

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the vs code proxy settings and see if "system certificates" is checked. If it is, try turning it off and restart vscode.
I'd guess that you have a self-signed proxy certificate and that vscode does not trust that.

Comment: I tried turning off and restarted vs code but it still didnt work